# Uninstall office 365 with script

Tags: windows

I have this list of office versions :
"Microsoft 365 - fr -fr"
"Microsoft 365 - en -en"
...

When I receive a new computer I need to uninstall these software, I have already tried with wmic, but when I type wmic product, these softs didn't appear.

Same thing for all Dell's software pre installed.

I have also try to take the uninstallString in registery, and put them in a .bat file but it didn't launch uninstallation.

What should I try ?

Comment: Try this command : "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeClickToRun.exe" scenario=install scenariosubtype=ARP sourcetype=None productstoremove=O365ProPlusRetail.16_fr-fr_x-none culture=fr-fr version.16=16.0 forceappshutdown=true DisplayLevel=False

Comment: Yes, that's the uninstallString right ? It work if I copy paste in a win terminal, but when I paste all the command in a bat file, nothing happen$

Comment: You run the bat "as administrator" ? You have a log file in your %temp% directory (computername-date-hour.log)